# Open date picker on button click

Tags: uwp, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

I want to use the built in date picker or calendar date picker but without the default view - I have a page that displays a list of data for the selected month - I have a button that when clicked should display the controls for changing the month - I only want the button, not the selected date showing.

The UI is like below, the calendar button (top right) should open the datepicker.
There doesn't seem to be a way to programmatically open this.

I can add a date picker to another page and display it within a content dialog but it doesn't look great.

It would be better if I could style the date picker to look like a button - but I can't find a way to do this.

Can anyone suggest any alternative approaches?[image: calendar button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is a [*DatePickerFlyout*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepickerflyout):

```xml
<Button Content="Choose date">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <DatePickerFlyout Date="{x:Bind ChosenDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

It will show the picker once you click the button. You can add the flyout to any control, however in some of them you will have to show it manually. With *Button* it will work automatically.

Comment: Awesome. New to UWP so hadn't even heard of flyouts before - thanks.

Comment: Thx.I have not found it that can help me to write the app.